# intersect date intervals and calculate value within them

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table containing "start_at", "finish_at" and "value" columns:

| start_at | finish_at | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:00 | 2022-11-01 22:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-11-01 16:00:00 | 2022-11-01 19:00:00 | 8 |
| 2022-11-01 18:00:00 | 2022-11-01 23:00:00 | 3 |

I want to aggregate date intervals and calculate max value within them. Expected result:

| start_at | finish_at | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-01 10:00:00 | 2022-11-01 16:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-11-01 16:00:00 | 2022-11-01 19:00:00 | 8 |
| 2022-11-01 19:00:00 | 2022-11-01 22:00:00 | 5 |
| 2022-11-01 22:00:00 | 2022-11-01 23:00:00 | 3 |

I tried `SELECT range_agg(tsrange(start_at, finish_at)), max(value) FROM my_table;` but the result is not exactly what I need:

| range_agg | max |
| --- | --- |
| {["2022-11-01 10:00:00","2022-11-01 23:00:00")} | 8 |

Answer (score 1):

setup.

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE test6 (
    start_at timestamp,
    finish_at timestamp,
    value numeric
);
INSERT INTO test6
    VALUES ('2022-11-01 10:00:00', '2022-11-01 22:00:00', 5),
    ('2022-11-01 16:00:00', '2022-11-01 19:00:00', 8),
    ('2022-11-01 18:00:00', '2022-11-01 23:00:00', 3);
CREATE VIEW test6v AS
SELECT
    tsrange(start_at, finish_at, '[)'),
    value
FROM
    test6;
COMMIT;
```

query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        tsrange(s, s + interval '3 hour', '[)') AS RANGE
    FROM (
        SELECT
            generate_series(min(start_at), max(finish_at), interval '3 hour')
        FROM
            test6) foo (s))
SELECT
    RANGE,
    max(value) FILTER (WHERE RANGE && tsrange IS TRUE)
FROM
    cte
    CROSS JOIN test6v
GROUP BY
    RANGE
ORDER BY
    RANGE;
```

- You can customize your desired interval range table. here I slice min(start_at), max(finish_at) based on interval '3 hour'.
- tsrange range function, third paramter, you can set the range bound be inclusive or not.
- group by custom tsrange then get the max value of value if custome tsrange intersect with test6's tsrange.

---

Almost identical to your expected result.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        tsrange(s, s + interval '3 hour', '[)') AS RANGE
    FROM ((
            SELECT
                generate_series('2022-11-01 16:00:00'::timestamp, max(finish_at), interval '3 hour')
            FROM
                test6)
        UNION (
            SELECT
                '2022-11-01 10:00:00'::timestamp)) s (s))
SELECT
    RANGE,
    max(value) FILTER (WHERE RANGE && tsrange IS TRUE)
FROM
    cte
    CROSS JOIN test6v
GROUP BY
    RANGE
ORDER BY
    RANGE;
```